# Laplace Transform for IVP of y(t)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Use the Laplace transform to solve the IVP for $y(t)$:
>             \begin{align*}
>           y''(t) + \omega^2y(t) = f(t) \qquad y(0) = y'(0) = 0
>       \end{align*}
>   where $f$ is a given function on $[0,\infty)$.

**My attempt to a solution:**

Taking the Laplace Transform on both sides, we get:
\begin{align*}
            \mathcal{L}\{y''(t) + \omega^2y(t)\}&=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}\\
            \mathcal{L}\{y''(t)\}(s)+\omega^2\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}(s)&=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}\\
            s^2\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}(s)-{sy(0)}-{y'(0)}+\omega^2\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}(s)&=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} \tag{applying ICs}\\
            (s^2+\omega^2)\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}(s)&=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}
\end{align*}

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Is it a matter of simply just moving $(s^2+\omega^2)$ to the RHS and that's it, or do I have to evaluate the RHS first?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not given you can only say that $y$ is the inverse Laplace transorm of $\frac {\mathcal L(f)(s)} {s^{2}+\omega^{2}}$.